# Gmail Go-to action markup schema

Tags: google-schemas

I used the [Google markup tester](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) to validate the sample markup from   [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action) and it says

> url: missing and required

When i replace **target** with **url**, validation is successful. Is it supposed to be target or url?

Comment: I did 2 tests, 1 with target and 1 with url using the Send Gmail Actions tool (http://gmail-actions.appspot.com). I was able to generate actions buttons using both target and url (http://i.stack.imgur.com/c7PkV.png) I'm not sure why target is giving an error in the markup tester when it's the example provided in their documentation. But I would say both are valid to use since both generate a button.

Comment: Confirmed with google, their validator needs to be fixed. Both target and url should work.